# abstract class type ... is not allowed, pure virtual function is not override

Tags: c++

I want to write little program with a few classes.

First class Number:

```
class Number
{
public:
    virtual int compare(Number& a) = 0;
    virtual string toString() = 0;
    virtual void fillRandom() = 0;
};
```

Second class Rational that inherits from Number

```
class Rational:Number
{
public:
    int l;
    int m;
    Rational(int a, int b)
    {
        this->l = a;
        this->m = b;
    }
    int compare(Rational a){}   // here is the problem
    string toString(){}
    void fillRandom(){}
};
```

I understand why I have this error, I have a pure virtual method `int compare(Number& a)` ,thus in all subclasses I must have same method.

But, if I change `compare` argument to `Number` it won't work without casting Number to Rational somewhere in `compare`.

Is there any way to do it without casting? Or what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Do you need polymorphism?

Comment: Yep, that's what I need

Comment: You can't do it with a cast either, as a `Number` parameter doesn't have to be a `Rational`.

Comment: Note that you are using private inheritance, you probably want `class Rational : public Number`.

Comment: @BoPersson they can use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to make sure it is a rational.

Comment: @BoPersson but can't I check an object's type and cast only after that?

Comment: A similar question (without a good solution) [How to inherit and implement a pure virtual method with the abstract base class as a parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419579/how-to-inherit-and-implement-a-pure-virtual-method-with-the-abstract-class-as-a?rq=1)

Comment: @AleksanderMonk - Ok, a `dynamic_cast` would do the job, but turns a compile time error into a run-time error. Not what I would want.  :-)

Comment: This is the only way to make sure that you are not comparing a Rational with a Complex number for example. Unless you are interested in adding the comparison support for other compatible derived classes.

Comment: Related: [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to have some content in order to compare. What is it?

a) Can the `Rational` only be compared with the other `Rational`? or

b) somehow `Value(Rational())` vs `Value(OtherNumber())`? where

```
class OtherNumber : public Number
{
     // Some code here
}
```

If a, then you need to think why you put the `compare()` into the super class.

If b, then you need to abstract the other function, say

```
virtual long Value() const = 0;
```

and alter `compare()` so it works on the `Value()`:

```
virtual int compare(const Number& a)
{
    // something about Value() and a.Value();
}
```

BTW, normally the compare function is a `const` function. That is:

```
virtual int compare ( const Number& a ) const;
```

Also, remember to extend the `Number` with `public`, i.e.

```
class Rational : public Number
```

Otherwise you will lose polymorphic behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by `NumberInOrderFormat`?

Comment: I update the answer. Just the other class implement the Number

Comment: I guess if you do the thing with `compare` working with `Value()`, you should make `compare` non-virtual, right?

Comment: yes, you are right. But declare the compare() as virtual enable the other class to override it again. Unless the class is a final class, or the function is definitely cannot be overrided, otherwise virtual is no harm. Of cause, except performance sensitive code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below signature (both in base and derived classes) (keeping the virtual declaration in the base):

```
int compare(const Number* a){}
```

So basically the idea is to use pointers instead of references. This should work and you don't have to perform any kind of casting to call the compare method.

However, with the code above you still have to dynamically cast *Number* to Rational in the compare method body. Additionally, you have to take into account that it's possible to call a compare with any subclass of Number and maybe you are not interested in this behavior. So you have to added some checks to make sure that you are comparing against an incompatible class.

Comment: How does using a pointer make a difference from using a reference?

Comment: They were not talking about casting to call but casting in the function itself.  You would still have to cast to a `Rational` in the function.

Comment: I understand when using the reference if you pass the derived class to a method that was defined to receive a base class so the passed value will be converted to the base class.

Comment: and that is the same behavior with a pointer.  you still have to cast back inside the function.

Comment: Yes, that will be needed in order to treat Number as Rational .. so yes, a cast will be needed in all cases.